# How does the bound in the large sieve depend on the norm on the lattice?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sieve-theory

I've been reading about the large sieve inequality in Serre's "Lectures on the Mordell-Weil theorem", which states it in the following setting, which I've simplified a bit here:

Suppose $\Lambda \cong \Bbb Z^n$ is a lattice and we have a norm $\| \cdot \|$ on $\Lambda_{\Bbb R} = \Lambda \otimes \Bbb R \cong \Bbb R^n$.

Then there is a constant $c = c(\Lambda, \|\cdot \|)$ depending only on $\Lambda$ and the norm $\| \cdot \|$, such that for any set $X$ with the following properties:

- $X$ is contained in a ball of radius $N$ for the norm  $\| \cdot \|$
- some "local sieving" conditions at primes $\le Q$,

we have $|X| \le c \sup(N^n, Q^{2n})/L(Q)$, where $L(Q)$ is a function of the local densities used in the sieve.

Is there a treatment of the large sieve that spells out how the upper bound in this sieve depends on the choice of norm $\| \cdot \|$, or equiavlently on the shape of the ball bounding $X$?  I don't want explicit constants, just a qualitative sense of the dependence.

I've looked at the example of Chapter 4 of Kowalski's book on the large sieve, which gives a bound in the case where the ball is a paralellepiped aligned with the coordinate axes, but I'm interested in a more general situation (e.g. a general parallelepiped or ellipsoid).

Comment: This is a great question. I haven't seen treatments like this in the literature. Do you have some specific application in mind? If your norms vary in some simple way (e.g. multiples of each other) then it is quite likely that one can just adapt the usual large sieve to your case.

Comment: For the application I'm thinking about, the balls for these norms are all of the form $gB$ where B is a fixed ball and g is some linear transformation, such that I'm in a situation where I can use Davenport's lemma to estimate the number of lattice points in B, and I'd like to get some sort of upper bound on the number of these points that lie in a thin subset.

Comment: You could also think instead of the lattice changing, rather than the norm, since applying $g^{-1}$ to $\Lambda$ gives a different lattice but with fixed norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to reduce to the parallelepiped case. Let $\Lambda'$ be the dual lattice of $\Lambda$ with the dual norm $$|| y|| =  sup_{x \in \Lambda} \frac{ x \cdot y}{ || x||}.$$ Let $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_n$ be the successive minima of $\Lambda'$. Let $w_1,\dots, w_n$ be the associated shortest vectors, forming a basis of $\Lambda'$. Let $v_1,\dots, v_n$ be the dual basis of $\Lambda$. Then we have

$$ \left|\left|\sum_i a_i v_i  \right|\right| \leq \sup_{j\in [n]} \frac{|\sum_i a_i v_i \cdot w_j|} { \lambda_j} = \sup_{j\in [n]} \frac{ |a_j| }{\lambda_j}$$ so the ball of radius $N$ is contained in the parallelepiped $$\left \{ \sum_i a_i v_i ,  |a_i| \leq \lambda_i N \right\}$$

and then you can apply the version from Kowalski's book.